# Splitting a file into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, split

I'm only a beginner python user so my apologies if this is a rather simple question. I have a file containing two lists divided by a tab. I would like to store this in a dictionary, so each entry is associated with the corresponding entry after the tab, such that:

```
cat hat
mouse bowl
rat nose
monkey uniform
dog whiskers
elephant dance
```

would be divided into

```
{'cat'; 'hat', 'mouse' ; 'bowl') etc. etc.
```

It's a very long list.

This is what I tried:

```
enhancerTAD = open('TAD_to_enhancer.map', 'r')
list = enhancerTAD.split()

for entry in list:
    key, val = entry.split('\t')
    ET[key] = val

print ET
```

Here's my most recent attempt, and the error message that I get below:

```
enhancerTAD = open('TAD_to_enhancer.map', 'r').read()
ET = {}
lst = enhancerTAD.split("\n")
for entry in lst:
  key, val = entry.strip().split(' ',1)
  ET[key] = val

enhancergene = open('enhancer_to_gene_map.txt', 'r').read()
GE = {}
lst1 = enhancergene.split("\n")
for entry in lst1:
  key, val = entry.strip().split(' ',1)
  GE[key] = val

geneTAD = open('TAD_to_gene_map.txt', 'r').read()
GT = {}
lst2 = geneTAD.split("\n")
for entry in lst2:
  key, val = entry.strip().split(' ',1)
  GT[key] = val
```

File "enhancertadmaybe.py", line 13, in 
    key, val = entry.strip().split(' ',1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: That's not a dictionary, do you want a `set`?also did you have tried anything so far?

Comment: Asking simple questions is very fine as long as you post your attempts and not just asking for a ready solution.

Comment: `with open('/path/to/file') as f: dict_object = {key: value for line in f for key, value in line.split()}`

Comment: @Kasramvd That's definitely not a `set` - he asked for associating each key with a value. The only way it could not be a `dict` is if he has duplicate keys.

Comment: @skyking duplicate keys do not make sense in a dictionary, neither do duplicates in general in a set. Actually, the keys in a dictionary are a set.

Comment: The example is quite poor - the columns does not seem to be tab separated as described.

Comment: @cnluzon But duplicate keys may appear in the file - in that case it cannot represent a `dict` since they does not make sense there (unless of course he has an idea on which key-value pair to ignore or something similar).

Comment: Hi guys I did try something but it didn't work very well:

Comment: enhancerTAD = open('TAD_to_enhancer.map', 'r')

list = enhancerTAD.split()
for entry in list:
  key, val = entry.split('\t')
  ET[key] = val
  print ET

Comment: @skyking I did not see in the OP's question any reference to duplicate keys. And in any case it's not defined what he'd want to do with duplicates. In that case a solution could be dict(str) -> list(str).

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
    print dict(line.strip().split('\t', 1) for line in f)
```

Result:

```
{'monkey': 'uniform', 'dog': 'whiskers', 'cat': 'hat', 'rat': 'nose', 'elephant': 'dance', 'mouse': 'bowl'}
```

Comment: First of all that would not work if there's more than one word on a line. Secondly it will not split according to the description - it's stated that they're separated by tab. So the correct split should be `line.strip().split('\t', 1)`.

Comment: I tried it and it returned a 'line' is not defined error. This was my original go: enhancerTAD = open('TAD_to_enhancer.map', 'r')

list = enhancerTAD.split()
for entry in list:
  key, val = entry.split('\t')
  ET[key] = val
  print ET

Comment: @oliver4444 never use the word `list` to name any variable it will shallow the `list function` and it is very messy to see I think you can edit your question

Answer (score 0):

Modification to your original method :

```
enhancerTAD = open('TAD_to_enhancer.map', 'r').read()
ET={}
lst = enhancerTAD.split("\n")
for entry in lst:
   key, val = entry.strip().split('\t',1)
   ET[key] = val
print ET
```

**Points:**

1.Your original method failed because were trying to split on a file object not the file content

**i.e)**

```
a=open("amazon1.txt","r")
c=a.split()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'
```

2.You have to read the content of the file to split it

**i.e.)**

```
enhancerTAD =open("amazon1.txt","r").read()
```

3.Since you have key,value pair in each line you have to split at new line initially

4.Then you can iterate over the list and again split it at `\t` and form the dictionary

`Juniorcomposer` method does all of this two line code and is more pythonic

Comment: Thank you! But it comes back saying that 'type' object is not iterable. What does this mean?

Comment: @oliver4444 could you add the full traceback that is which line saying the error and what is the full error